# Using custom API and struck at it

Tags: java, api

im using java to build a project and im at beginner level in java so i encountered a problem

i am using gsql parser's java api to parse database queries and there is one little point where i have stuck up

there are 2 classes TSelectSqlStatement & TCreateTableSqlStatement both inherit TCustomSqlStatement class and i have to use a method in Createtable in SelectSql and when i do this type casting isnt allowed

is there any way to solve this problem??

link for the api reference is

http://www.sqlparser.com/kb/javadoc/

this is the DBSystem.java

```
    package dbs;

import gudusoft.gsqlparser.EDbVendor;
import gudusoft.gsqlparser.TCustomSqlStatement;
import gudusoft.gsqlparser.TGSqlParser;
import gudusoft.gsqlparser.nodes.TColumnDefinition;
import gudusoft.gsqlparser.nodes.TConstraint;
import gudusoft.gsqlparser.nodes.TResultColumn;
import gudusoft.gsqlparser.stmt.TCreateTableSqlStatement;
import gudusoft.gsqlparser.stmt.TSelectSqlStatement;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class DBSystem extends printSelect 
{
    static String tName=null;
    static String s=null;   
    static boolean a=true;

    static String config_path="tmp\\config.txt";


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        TGSqlParser sqlparser = new TGSqlParser(EDbVendor.dbvoracle);

        try
        {

            BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            s = bufferRead.readLine();

        }

        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sqlparser.sqltext=s.toString();

        int ret = sqlparser.parse();
        if (ret == 0)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<sqlparser.sqlstatements.size();i++)
            {
                analyzeStmt(sqlparser.sqlstatements.get(i));
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Query Invalid: \n Reason: \n");
            System.out.println(sqlparser.getErrormessage());
        }

    }

    protected static void analyzeStmt(TCustomSqlStatement stmt) throws IOException
    {
        switch(stmt.sqlstatementtype)
        {
            case sstselect:
                analyzeSelectStmt((TSelectSqlStatement)stmt);
                break;
            case sstcreatetable:
                analyzeCreateStmt((TCreateTableSqlStatement)stmt);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(stmt.sqlstatementtype.toString());
        }
    }

    private static void printSelectStmt(TCustomSqlStatement stmt) throws IOException
    {
        String p=stmt.getTargetTable().toString();

        System.out.println(p);

        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(p+".csv"));     
        String line;
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();
    }


    private static void analyzeCreateStmt(TCreateTableSqlStatement pStmt) 
    {
        System.out.println("\nQuery Type: Create ");

        tName=pStmt.getTargetTable().toString();

        System.out.println("\nTable Name: \t"+pStmt.getTargetTable().toString());
        System.out.println("\nColumns: \n");
        TColumnDefinition column;
        for(int i=0;i<pStmt.getColumnList().size();i++)
        {
            column = pStmt.getColumnList().getColumn(i);
            System.out.println("\tname:"+column.getColumnName().toString());
            System.out.println("\tdatetype:"+column.getDatatype().toString());

            if (column.getDefaultExpression() != null)
            {
                    System.out.println("\tdefault:"+column.getDefaultExpression().toString());
            }

            if (column.isNull())
            {
                    System.out.println("\tnull: yes");
            }

            if (column.getConstraints() != null)
            {
                System.out.println("\tinline constraints:");
                for(int j=0;j<column.getConstraints().size();j++)
                {
                   printConstraint(column.getConstraints().getConstraint(j),false);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        if(pStmt.getTableConstraints().size() > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\toutline constraints:");
            for(int i=0;i<pStmt.getTableConstraints().size();i++)
            {
                printConstraint(pStmt.getTableConstraints().getConstraint(i), true);
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }

        try {
            checkTable();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void checkTable() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    {

        FileInputStream fstream1 = new FileInputStream(config_path);  
        DataInputStream in1 = new DataInputStream(fstream1);
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));

        while (br1.readLine() != null)   
        {
            //create table test(tid int,tname string);

            do
            {
                if(tName.equalsIgnoreCase(br1.readLine()))
                {
                    a=false;

                    //System.out.println("tName == br1.readLine()");
                    System.out.println("Query Invalid: \n \t Table already exists");
                    break;
                }
            }while(br1.readLine() != null);

            if(a==true)
            {
                createTableHeader1();
                break;
            }           

        }

        br1.close();

    }


    private static void createTableHeader1() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    {
        String p=s;
        int strt_index=p.indexOf("(");
        int end_index =p.indexOf(")");

        String x=p.substring(strt_index+1, end_index);
        //System.out.println(x);

        int count=1;
        for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++)
        {
            if(x.charAt(i)==',')
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        String[] parts=x.split(",");

        /*PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(tName +".data", "UTF-8");
        PrintWriter writer1 =new PrintWriter(tName +".csv", "UTF-8");
        writer.close();
        writer1.close();*/

        try {

              File file = new File(tName+".data");
              File file1 = new File(tName+".csv");

              if (file.createNewFile())
              {
                System.out.println(tName+".data is created");
              }
              else
              {
                System.out.println("File already exists.");
              }

              if (file1.createNewFile())
              {
                System.out.println(tName+".csv is created");
              }
              else
              {
                System.out.println("File already exists.");
              }

            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileWriter write= new FileWriter(config_path,true);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =new BufferedWriter(write);
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
        bufferedWriter.write("BEGIN");

        bufferedWriter.newLine();
        bufferedWriter.write(tName);
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
        //attribute list , Data type
        for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
        {
            //System.out.println(j);
            bufferedWriter.write(parts[j]);
            //System.out.println(parts[0]);
            //System.out.println(parts[1]);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
        }

        bufferedWriter.write("END");
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }


    protected static void printConstraint(TConstraint constraint, Boolean outline)
    {
        if (constraint.getConstraintName() != null)
        {
            System.out.println("\t\tconstraint name:"+constraint.getConstraintName().toString());
        }

        switch(constraint.getConstraint_type())
        {
            case notnull:
                System.out.println("\t\tnot null");
                break;
            case primary_key:
                System.out.println("\t\tprimary key");
                if (outline)
                {
                    String lcstr = "";
                    if (constraint.getColumnList() != null)
                    {
                        for(int k=0;k<constraint.getColumnList().size();k++)
                        {
                            if (k !=0 )
                            {
                                lcstr = lcstr+",";
                            }
                            lcstr = lcstr+constraint.getColumnList().getObjectName(k).toString();
                        }
                        System.out.println("\t\tprimary key columns:"+lcstr);
                    }
                }
                break;

            case unique:
                System.out.println("\t\tunique key");
                if(outline)
                {
                    String lcstr="";
                    if (constraint.getColumnList() != null)
                    {
                        for(int k=0;k<constraint.getColumnList().size();k++)
                        {
                            if (k !=0 )
                            {
                                lcstr = lcstr+",";
                            }
                            lcstr = lcstr+constraint.getColumnList().getObjectName(k).toString();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("\t\tcolumns:"+lcstr);
                }
                break;

            case check:
                System.out.println("\t\tcheck:"+constraint.getCheckCondition().toString());
                break;

            case foreign_key:
                //case reference:

                System.out.println("\t\tforeign key");
                if(outline)
                {
                    String lcstr="";
                    if (constraint.getColumnList() != null)
                    {
                        for(int k=0;k<constraint.getColumnList().size();k++)
                        {
                            if (k !=0 )
                            {
                                lcstr = lcstr+",";
                            }
                            lcstr = lcstr+constraint.getColumnList().getObjectName(k).toString();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("\t\tcolumns:"+lcstr);
                }
                System.out.println("\t\treferenced table:"+constraint.getReferencedObject().toString());
                if (constraint.getReferencedColumnList() != null)
                {
                    String lcstr="";
                    for(int k=0;k<constraint.getReferencedColumnList().size();k++)
                    {
                        if (k !=0 )
                        {
                            lcstr = lcstr+",";
                        }
                        lcstr = lcstr+constraint.getReferencedColumnList().getObjectName(k).toString();
                    }
                    System.out.println("\t\treferenced columns:"+lcstr);
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }


    protected static void analyzeSelectStmt(TSelectSqlStatement pStmt) throws IOException  
    {
        System.out.println("\nQuery Type: Select ");

        if (pStmt.isCombinedQuery())
        {
            String setstr="";
            switch (pStmt.getSetOperator())
            {
                case 1: setstr = "union";
                    break;
                case 2: setstr = "union all";
                    break;
                case 3: setstr = "intersect";
                    break;
                case 4: setstr = "intersect all";
                    break;
                case 5: setstr = "minus";
                    break;
                case 6: setstr = "minus all";
                    break;
                case 7: setstr = "except";
                    break;
                case 8: setstr = "except all";
                    break;
            }

            System.out.printf("set type: %s\n",setstr);
            System.out.println("left select:");
            analyzeSelectStmt(pStmt.getLeftStmt());
            System.out.println("right select:");
            analyzeSelectStmt(pStmt.getRightStmt());

            /*if (pStmt.getOrderbyClause() != null)
            {
                System.out.printf("order by clause %s\n",pStmt.getOrderbyClause().toString());
            }*/
        }

        else
        {
            //select list
            for(int i=0; i < pStmt.getResultColumnList().size();i++)
            {
                TResultColumn resultColumn = pStmt.getResultColumnList().getResultColumn(i);
                System.out.printf("\tColumn: %s\n",resultColumn.getExpr().toString());
            }


            //where clause
            if (pStmt.getWhereClause() != null)
            {
                System.out.printf("\nwhere clause: \n\t%s\n", pStmt.getWhereClause().getCondition().toString());
            }

            // group by
            if (pStmt.getGroupByClause() != null)
            {
                //System.out.printf("\ngroup by: \n\t%s\n",pStmt.getGroupByClause().toString());
                System.out.printf("\nGroup by:");
                for(int i=0;i<pStmt.getGroupByClause().getItems().size();i++)
                {
                    System.out.printf("\n\t%s",pStmt.getGroupByClause().getItems().getGroupByItem(i).toString());
                }
            }

            // order by
            if (pStmt.getOrderbyClause() != null)
                {
                System.out.printf("\norder by:");
                for(int i=0;i<pStmt.getOrderbyClause().getItems().size();i++)
                {
                System.out.printf("\n\t%s",pStmt.getOrderbyClause().getItems().getOrderByItem(i).toString());
                }
            }

            // for update
            if (pStmt.getForUpdateClause() != null)
            {
                System.out.printf("for update: \n%s\n",pStmt.getForUpdateClause().toString());
            }

            // top clause
            if (pStmt.getTopClause() != null)
            {
                System.out.printf("top clause: \n%s\n",pStmt.getTopClause().toString());
            }
        }

        //check if table is present or not. if present open tablename.csv and tablename.data

        printSelect.main(null);

    }
}
```

this is the printSelect.java

```
package dbs;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import gudusoft.gsqlparser.EDbVendor;
import gudusoft.gsqlparser.TCustomSqlStatement;
import gudusoft.gsqlparser.TGSqlParser;
import gudusoft.gsqlparser.stmt.TCreateTableSqlStatement;

public class printSelect
{
    static String p=null,tName;
    static int x=0,y=0;
    static boolean s=false;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {       
        TGSqlParser sqlparser = new TGSqlParser(EDbVendor.dbvoracle);
        p=DBSystem.s;
        System.out.println(p);
        sqlparser.sqltext=p.toString();

        int ret = sqlparser.parse();
        if (ret == 0)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<sqlparser.sqlstatements.size();i++)
            {
                //analyze(sqlparser.sqlstatements.get(i));
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }

    }

    public static void analyze(TCustomSqlStatement stmnt) throws IOException
    {       
        x=checkPresent((TCreateTableSqlStatement)stmnt);
        if(x==1)
        {
            printSelect((TCreateTableSqlStatement)stmnt);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Table Doesnt exist");
        }

    }

    private static int checkPresent(TCreateTableSqlStatement stmnt) throws IOException 
    {
        tName=stmnt.getTargetTable().toString();

        FileInputStream fstream1 = new FileInputStream(DBSystem.config_path);  
        DataInputStream in1 = new DataInputStream(fstream1);
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));

        while (br1.readLine() != null)   
        {           
            do
            {
                if(!(tName.equalsIgnoreCase(br1.readLine())))
                {
                    s=true;                 
                    y=0;
                }
            }while(br1.readLine() != null);


            if(s==false)
            {
                y=1;
            }                       
        }

        br1.close();
        return y;       
    }

    private static void printSelect(TCreateTableSqlStatement stmnt) throws IOException 
    {
        tName=stmnt.getTargetTable().toString();
        System.out.println(tName);
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tName+".csv"));     
        String line;
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

This is the error when compiled

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: gudusoft.gsqlparser.stmt.TSelectSqlStatement cannot be cast to gudusoft.gsqlparser.stmt.TCreateTableSqlStatement
    at dbs.printSelect.analyze(printSelect.java:43)
    at dbs.printSelect.main(printSelect.java:34)
    at dbs.DBSystem.analyzeSelectStmt(DBSystem.java:758)
    at dbs.DBSystem.analyzeStmt(DBSystem.java:364)
    at dbs.DBSystem.main(DBSystem.java:347)

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. Sharing a common ancestor is not enough. A TSelectSqlStatement is not a TCreateTableSqlStatement so any member function introduced by TCreateTableSqlStatement cannot be called on an object of type TSelectSqlStatement. If you could force the compiler todo it most likely it would crash horribly anyway because the function wouldn't know how to do the right thing.

If you need a work around then specify in your question which particular function you need. It might be possible to achieve in another way.

Comment: i should use getTargetTable method and when it returns i'll convert it to a string.

Comment: That function is declared on the base class TCustomSqlStatement  so you shouldn't have any problem calling it. Please edit your question to include the code you tried and the error you are getting from the compiler.

Comment: I have edited the code to include the code as well as the error